A question regarding the deformation retraction of a ball without origin to a sphere.
Let $D=\{||x||\leq 1\}\subset \mathbb R^d$ be a ball or radius $1$ with center at origin $O$ and let $H:\overline (D\setminus\{O\})\times[0,1]\to D\setminus\{O\}$ be a strong deformation retraction to $\partial D$, that is:
$H(x,0)=x$ for all $x\in D\setminus\{O\}$.
$H(x,1)\in \partial D$ for all $x\in D\setminus\{O\}$.
$H(y,t)=y$ for all $y\in\partial D$ and $t\in [0,1]$.
Moreover, we have $(*):$ $H(H(x,t),s)=H(x,t+s)$ for all $x$ and $t,s\geq 0$ with $t+s\leq 1$. (In other words, $H$ is a (restriction) of a topologycal flow.)
We consider the function $f:D\setminus\{0\}\to [0,1]$, $f(x)=\inf\{t\;:\;H(x,t)\in\partial D\}$. Is it true that $f$ is continuous on the sphere $\partial D$ (or maybe on $D\setminus\{O\}$)?
Remark: Without the assumption $(*)$, the statement is false. Take for instance
$H(x,t)=(1-t)x+\frac{t}{||x||}x$. Then $f(x)=1$ in the interior of $D$ and $f(x)=0$ on $\partial D$, hence $f$ is not continuous on $\partial D$.
However, if $H(x,t)$ satisfies $(*)$, it seems to work. For instance, if $H(x,t)=\begin{cases} x+\frac{t}{||x||}x, & t\in [0, 1-||x||) \\ \frac{x}{||x||}, & t \in [1-||x||,1] \end{cases}$, then it is easy to check $(*)$ and moreover $f(x)=1-||x||$ is continuos (not only on the border, but on $D\setminus \{O\}$).

Can you add an example of a strong deformation retraction satisfying $(*)$?

I take it $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

You always have $f(x)=0$ for $x\in \partial D$, so $f$ is continuous on $\partial D$. Do you want continuity on $D\setminus 0$?

$f$ is not necessarily continuous on $\partial D$ relative to its domain $D \setminus 0$.

I want $lim_{D\ni x\to y}f(x)=f(y)=0$ for all $y\in\partial D$.
